# Selenium how to get all Xpath's from the page

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium

iam trying to get all object's xpath's from loaded page via selenium

something similar to the funkction that selenium allready have:

selenium.getAllbuttons();

problem is that i cant use this funkction and work with id's because they are all dynamically generated every time when a new page is loaded.

Any ideas how to get all object's xpath's from loaded page?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
xpathcount = selenium.getXpathCount("//input");
for (i = 0;i<xpathcount;i+=1){
   selenium.click("//input["+i+"]");

}
```

The above code will click on all the buttons that have input tags and go from the top to the bottom.

The main thing that you want to do is `selenium.doSomething("//input["+i+"]")`; where doSomething is any Selenium Command.

Comment: first of all thank you for quick answer

your code is nice and helpfull but my problem is not to locate all xpath's but write them down to the file or screen. with your piece of code i can easily find all of xpath's of all object (actually its not good enaugh because it will find them all and i really dont need every xpath for every div etc... but that i will figure out later how to extract only xpath's for object's that i need e.g. buttons fields combo boxes etc.)

Comment: if its possible please write me here a piece of code that will write one xpath for example to the screen or file, thank you

Comment: in c# use the Console.Writeline or with Java it would be System.out.println with the xpath.

The code that I put above would only give you items that have the input tag e.g <input .... />. it wouldnt give you divs or that.